# sql server 2008 remote connection login

Tags: sql, sql-server, connection

I am using SQL Server 2008 r2. Did the following steps. But it does not allow me to remotely connect to the server.

1) On PC-1, logged in through windows authentication mode. (`server name=My-PC` and `username=amp\user1` )

2) Under Security tab, Created new login say u1.

3) then created new database under Databases node sat test with u1 as owner.

I want that from another PC say PC-2 which is on same network as My-PC, I want to login to test DB with u1 user.

On My-PC I Followed the steps specified [Here](http://www.linglom.com/2009/03/28/enable-remote-connection-on-sql-server-2008-express/).

But When I try to connect from PC-2 to test, it gives following error. What step I am missing?

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to sql server. A server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL server configuration to allow remote connections. (provider: Named pipes provider, error 40- could not open a connection to sql server) (Microsoft SQL server, Error: 5)

Comment: Connecting from another computer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345343.aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the Windows firewall settings on both machines?

See [here](http://www.med-sites.com/Manual/hg/StepForSQLServer/ForSQLServer.html) 
under "Configuring your firewall for SQL Server"

That's usually the next thing I would check because I don't think the firewall is mentioned in the link you listed except in the comments.

Comment: thanks a lot. It solved my problem. I added as an exception a port for TCP 1433. Now it allows to connect to.